# Typo in HTML tab of Markdown editor help

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing-help

[image]

Comment: They are tree-based after dinner confections used to sweeten the breath.  Related - `Corktails`

Comment: It should be _helmets_.

Comment: Aw hell naw.  You just raised the screenshot bar.  [Challenge accepted.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HjPtZ.jpg)

Comment: Don't know where the parrot comes from, I thought you'd have used http://s3.amazonaws.com/kym-assets/entries/icons/original/000/000/015/orly.jpg?1229112642

Comment: @Damien: that's my distant cousin who lives in an uncomfortable climate.

Comment: I genuinely laughed out loud when I read this one. Well done, well done indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This egregious error against human kind will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Fix confirmed on both meta and SO. Thanks! :)